# Согласование слова «роды» или что лучше вообще употребить?

Tags: выбор-слов

Предложение: «В прошлом году зафиксировано 142 родов (-а), хотя ерунда... 142 случая родов?) матерей, заражённых ВИЧ». Или лучше переделать предложение: «В прошлом году 142 женщины, зараженные ВИЧ, родили детей»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зафиксированы 142 новорождённых с ВИЧ.

Зафиксировано 142 случая ВИЧ у новорождённых.

Зафиксировано 142 новорождённых у рожениц с ВИЧ.

Зафиксированы 142 ВИЧ-инфицированные роженицы.

Зафиксированы роды у 142 ВИЧ-инфицированных рожениц.